# JanusGraph not communicating with Cassandra backend in Docker environment

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cassandra, dockerfile, janusgraph

I need your help on configuiring a docker compose file.

Problem : Created a custom build docker file ( janusgraph ) and trying to make it talk to other containers ( cassandra ) but it doesn't as it shows the below error..

```
janusgraph-es  | 2449 [main] ERROR org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor  - Could not invoke constructor on class org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager (defined by the 'graphManager' setting) with one argument of class Settings
janusgraph-es  | Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
janusgraph-es  |    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:91)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:122)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.<init>(GremlinServer.java:86)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer.main(GremlinServer.java:345)
janusgraph-es  | Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
janusgraph-es  |    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
janusgraph-es  |    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
janusgraph-es  |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
janusgraph-es  |    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.util.ServerGremlinExecutor.<init>(ServerGremlinExecutor.java:80)
janusgraph-es  |    ... 3 more
janusgraph-es  | Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager
janusgraph-es  |    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:64)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getImplementationClass(Backend.java:440)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.Backend.getStorageManager(Backend.java:411)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.configuration.builder.GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.build(GraphDatabaseConfigurationBuilder.java:50)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.lambda$open$0(JanusGraphFactory.java:150)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager.openGraph(JanusGraphManager.java:243)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:150)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory.open(JanusGraphFactory.java:100)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager.lambda$new$0(JanusGraphManager.java:75)
janusgraph-es  |    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager.<init>(JanusGraphManager.java:74)
janusgraph-es  |    ... 8 more
janusgraph-es  | Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
janusgraph-es  |    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
janusgraph-es  |    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
janusgraph-es  |    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
janusgraph-es  |    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.janusgraph.util.system.ConfigurationUtil.instantiate(ConfigurationUtil.java:58)
janusgraph-es  |    ... 18 more
janusgraph-es  | Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
janusgraph-es  |    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:268)
janusgraph-es  |    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:107)
janusgraph-es  |    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.negotiateProtocolVersionAndConnect(Cluster.java:1813)
janusgraph-es  |    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1726)
janusgraph-es  |    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:214)
janusgraph-es  |    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:387)
janusgraph-es  |    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connectAsync(Cluster.java:366)
janusgraph-es  |    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.connect(Cluster.java:311)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.initializeSession(CQLStoreManager.java:320)
janusgraph-es  |    at org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cql.CQLStoreManager.<init>(CQLStoreManager.java:182)
janusgraph-es  |    ... 23 more
```

Sharing the Dockerfile and the docker compose file

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-slim-buster

USER root
RUN mkdir -p /janusgraph

COPY . /janusgraph/.

WORKDIR /janusgraph/bin/

CMD ["./gremlin-server.sh"]
```

docker compose

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:3
    container_name: cassandra
    ports:
      - "9042:9042"
      - "9160:9160"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ $$(nodetool statusgossip) = running ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
    networks:
      - jce-network
    volumes:
      - app-volume:/var/lib/cassandra
  janusgraph-es:
#    image: docker.io/janusgraph/janusgraph:0.5.3
    build: ./janusgraph-full-0.5.3
    container_name: janusgraph-es
#    environment:
#      JANUS_PROPS_TEMPLATE: cql-es
#      janusgraph.storage.hostname: cassandra
#      janusgraph.index.search.hostname: elastic
#      graph.replace-instance-if-exists: true
    ports:
      - "8182:8182"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "bin/gremlin.sh", "-e", "scripts/remote-connect.groovy"]
      interval: 10000s
      timeout: 3000s
      retries: 3
    links:
      - "cassandra"
    networks:
      - jce-network
networks:
  jce-network:
volumes:
  app-volume:
```

FYI : I have edited the config of janusgraph by giving cassandra_container ip and also localhost and also if I start janusgraph manually with cassandra as docker service, it works!!

But not able to connect with using janusgraph as a docker service to cassandra.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `NoHostAvailableException` in the stacktrace indicates that the Cassandra Java driver used by JanusGraph can't connect to the cluster:

```
    ...
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /127.0.0.1:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [/127.0.0.1:9042] Cannot connect))
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:268)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:107)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.negotiateProtocolVersionAndConnect(Cluster.java:1813)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1726)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.init(Cluster.java:214)
    ...
```

I suspect that the problem is JanusGraph attempts to connect to the cluster before Cassandra is up and ready.

Try configuring your JanusGraph service to have a dependency on your Cassandra service (with `depends_on`). This means that the DB will be started before the app. Additionally, require that Cassandra is "healthy" before creating the JanusGraph service with the `condition` property.

Your Docker compose file should look like:

```
  ...
  janusgraph-es:
    ...
    depends_on:
      cassandra:
        condition: service_healthy
  ...
```

For details, see the official [Docker Docs `depends_on` specification](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on).

As a side note, [container `links` is a legacy feature](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) and is deprecated. Consider [using the default `bridge`](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) in your network configuration. Cheers!

```
networks:
  jce-network:
    driver: bridge
```

---

Please support the Apache Cassandra community by hovering over the [cassandra](/questions/tagged/cassandra) tag then click on the `Watch tag` button.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! it works now looks like as mentioned cassandra takes time to load hence janusgraph fails to connect. After adding the dependecy tag it behaves normally now.

Comment: Glad to hear that you got it working! 